# Next Js build failed due to Export encountered errors on following paths: in Next JS 14

Tags: next.js

I am building an ecommerce website using Next.js, and I encountered an error during the build process. When attempting to build the website, the following error occurred:

> ```
>  Export encountered errors on following paths:
>     /page: /
>     /productdetail/page: /productdetail
>     /products/page: /products
>     /success/page: /success
> ```

After a user makes a payment, I tried to retrieve the session ID from app/success/page. However, when using const { get } = useSearchParams(); to retrieve the session ID, the error occurs during build time. If I remove const { get } = useSearchParams();, the application builds successfully.

How can I resolve this issue?

Here is my code:

**app/success/page.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { SuccessComponent } from "@/components/SuccessComponent";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";

export default function SuccessPage() {
  const { get } = useSearchParams();
  const sessionId = get("session_id");

  return (
    <div>
      {sessionId ? (
        <SuccessComponent sessionId={sessionId} />
      ) : (
        <div>
         Nothing here to show
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```